# string in bison bison flex strdup

Tags: c++, string, bison, flex-lexer, strdup

im have a flex-bison project working on ubuntu linux vmPlayer.
Problem is, I'm trying to use map of string and int in my bison file for int-string casting, and it gives me error in file extra.y:

```
   %{   
   #include <stdio.h> 
   #include <stdlib.h>  
   #include <string.h>
   #include <map>
   using namespace std; 
   int yylex();   
   void yyerror(const char*);
   map<string,int> vars;   //ERROR
```

Error it give me:

```
 extra.y:9:12: error: ‘string’ was not declared in this scope
    map<string,int> vars;
```

..HELP ??

Comment: `#include <string>` (which is *not* even similar to `#include <string.h>`)

Comment: it still doesn't work, but why is it not similar to it? what is the difference ?

Comment: C++ strings and C strings are completely different. `#include <string.h>` gets you functions for C-style strings, which are not at all the same thing as the C++ data type `string`. For C++ `string`, use `#include <string>`.